# How to paste the copied code on a new line in Google Colab notebook?

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to paste the copied code on a new line in Google Colab notebook?

#Import the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

I have easily done it here, but couldn't do it in Google Colab

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab is essentially a Jupyter Notebook on cloud. Jupyter Notebook has two modes:

- Edit mode: This mode allows you to make changes to contents of a cell.
- Command mode: This mode allows you to make general changes to the notebook.

Click inside a cell. This will switch to edit mode and allow you paste contents into the selected cell.